# Internalization i18n codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I use internalization i18n ci.

The translation is fine but the home page always keeps the navigator's default language.

For example, i click on a link to translate (for example spanish) that's fine but if i click on the home link, my spanish translation is replaced by english (firefox is in english by default)

Please could you help me?

---

Thanks Sukunar,
When I use internalization i18ci, it automatically redirects with subdomain.
For example: 
Firefox with english like default language my home will be automatically: "http://localhost:8888/mysite/en/home"
If i choose a translation for example french, it will become: "http://localhost:8888/mysite/fr/home"
If i click on a link the language will be stored.
For example: A link to subscribe page will be: "http://localhost:8888/mysite/fr/translate"
If i come back to my home page with a link, it will be the default language of the browser and my selected language disappear.

This my file: Applications/config/routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = '';
//URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|fr)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(en|fr)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

May I change something in another file? and if it's this case how and what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sessions to store the user's language. Before loading a page, get the user's language from the session and display relevant content.

Alternatively, you can use a different URL structure or sub-domains for different languages. In this case, you need to make sure all yours links reflect the change in the language. This is also recommended from SEO perspective since web crawlers will be able to access this data.

For example,

site.com - default, in english

es.site.com - language specific, in spanish
site.com/es

Hope it helps!